# Open minicart box after click addtocart button

Tags: magento2

I have to open minicart box after addtocart button click. Is it possible to using section.xml? Anyone know about sections.xml usage in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

What are exactly those sections?

A section is a piece of customer data grouped together. Each section is represented by the key that is used to access and manage data and data itself. Magento loads sections by AJAX request to /customer/section/load/ and caches loaded data in the browser local storage under the key mage-cache-storage. Magento tracks when some section is changed and load updated section automatically.

How do you define a section?

A section defined in di.xml file by adding a new section into sections pool

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface">
<arguments>
    <argument name="sectionSourceMap" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="cart" xsi:type="string">Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart</item>
        <item name="directory-data" xsi:type="string">Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DirectoryData</item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

So here two new sections are registered cart and directory-data. Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart and Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\DirectoryData implements Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface and provides actual data as result of getSectionData method.

How are the section updates triggered?

Magento assumes that customer's private data is changed when a customer sends some state modification requests (POST, PUT, DELETE). To minimize the load on the server, developers should specify which action (or request) updates which customer data section in etc/section.xml.

```
<action name="checkout/cart/add">
  <section name="cart"/>
</action>
```

Action name is an action key pattern. When a user calls to action that matches specified pattern Magento will detect that the corresponding section is outdated and loads it again. If the action name is * that means that section will be updated on each POST and PUT request. If section tag is missed then all sections will be updated.

So conceptually this is wrong to update mini cart when you rich cart page. At this point, the mini cart (or cart section) already should be updated.

You can find more information about Customer Data [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html)

Answer (score -1):

There is already a full-fledged free extension available on Magento's marketplace and Github

magento: https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-slidingcart.html

Github: https://github.com/ambab-infotech/slidingcart

This might help someone.

Reference URL: https://roshanyadav007.wordpress.com/2020/01/24/sliding-cart-extension-for-magento-2-magento-2-3-x/

Comment: Why is this a separate answer?